# The SDK directory does not exist - non-latin path

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I recently updated my Android Studio to 0.3.6. My old projects weren't using Gradle,  but I tried to start a new one, and I'm getting the following error:

> The SDK directory 'C:\Users*gibberish*\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk' does not exist.

My user name is not in latin characters, and it seems it reads the path wrong, although I checked the local.properties file, and it is typed correctly, and in UTF-8 encoding. I tested with older versions (such as 0.3.2, which is current stable) and the problem does not exist.

I read about problems with the new gradle plugin etc, and since the project's files are created, maybe this is another gradle issue?

Should I just revert to the stable version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Windows and your pathname has non-ISO-8859 characters in it, there's a known bug that will prevent Android Studio from dealing with it properly; see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56102. This is actually a longstanding Java bug that will be pretty difficult for us to work around.

I'd recommend putting your projects in a path that doesn't include non-ISO-8859 characters.

Comment: This is sad. How did it come that it didn't show up with previous versions? I mean, it does work on version 0.3.2...

Answer (score 0):

In my Eclipse ADT setup, under the project root I added a file with name:   **local.properties**

In that file, I have one line:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/my_username/tools/android-sdk-macosx
```

It solved the issue.  I found the solution at [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure)

They have this note below.  I did have ANDROID_HOME set, but was still getting the error until I added the properties file (.. not sure why?!)

> Note: You will also need a ***local.properties*** file to set the location
>   of the SDK in the same way that the existing SDK requires, using the
>   sdk.dir property. Alternatively, you can set an environment variable
>   called ANDROID_HOME. There is no differences between the two methods,
>   you can use the one you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Windows you should first make sure your **enviornment variables** are set correctly.

create ANDROID_HOME if you don't have it, make sure it is set to  `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.

No need for the `local.properties` file for me after that.